# Optional with additional processing before orElse

Tags: java, option-type

In my service I want to return the MAX+1 OR return 10000000 instead, I have `fooRepository.findMax()` which return an `Optional<Long>` which is the MAX.

How to do it in just one line like below (I miss just the increment part)

```
fooRepository.findMax().orElse(10000000L)
```

PS: I know I can do it in multiple lines with `ifPresent` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the map method to do something with the contents of the Optional. If the Optional is empty, it is not executed.

Like this:

```
fooRepository.findMax()
    .map(max -> max + 1)
    .orElse(10000000L);
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a weird requirement, but why not just do...

```
fooRepository.findMax().orElse(9999999L) + 1
```

?

Answer (score 3):

That's what `map` is for:

```java
fooRepository.findMax().map(m -> m + 1).orElse(10000000L)
```